# How do I maximise the first real root of a multi-variable polynomial in x?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a polynomial in x, that also depends on {y1,y2,y3,y4,y5}. It always has 10 (not necessarily distinct) real roots. It's top coefficient is (1*x^10)  I aim to find the y's that maximize the smallest root.  I know of the Minimize command, but I haven't worked with roots before.

Actually, the polynomial is the determinant of a 10*10 symmetric matrix of the form (M + Ix) + (N1 y1 + N2 y2 .. + N5 y5) . So it can be restated as maximizing its smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: It seems more profitable to treat this as an symmetric eigenvalue maximization problem than a generic root maximization problem. There seems to be a bunch of specialized methods for this route, but I have no experience with them.

Comment: Is this a "matrix pencil" problem? It might be worth investigating related techniques.

Comment: It's hard to say without an example, but you could try `NMaximize[Min[Eigenvalues[matrix]], {x, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}]`

Comment: Perhaps, you could provide a simplified problem, perhaps a 4x4 matrix with two parameters, for readers to solve.  By the way, remember that the value of the minimum eigenvalue is only piecewise an analytical function of the parameters.

Comment: The NMaximize arpoach is what I ended up going for. It seems to work. (unless it was a local maximum, but that's irrelevant. I've figured out the behavior I was interested in)